# Commutative algebra counterexample

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $M$ be an $R[x]$-module, such that $M$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module.

Does there exist one such $M$, such that $M\otimes_{R[x]}R[x,x^{-1}]$ is not finitely generated as an $R$-module?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and let $M=\mathbb{Z}$ with $x$ acting by $2$.  Then $M\otimes_{R[x]}R[x,x^{-1}]\cong \mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ is not finitely generated over $R$.